# why is my sound not playing

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, unityscript, gameobject

```
private var doorIsOpen : boolean = false;
private var doorTimer : float = 0.0;
private var currentDoor : GameObject;

var doorOpenTime : float = 3.0;
var doorOpenSound : AudioClip;
var doorShutSound : AudioClip;

function OpenDoor (door : GameObject)
{   
    doorIsOpen = true;
    door.audio.PlayOneShot(doorOpenSound);
    door.transform.parent.animation.Play("doorOpen");
}

function OnControllerColliderHit (hit : ControllerColliderHit)
{

    if(hit.gameObject.tag == "playerDoor" && doorIsOpen == false)
    {
        OpenDoor(hit.gameObject);       
    }
}
```

this is supposed to play a sound when my character collides with a door but it doesn't i can't understand why

Comment: Are you sure this isn't ActionScript?

Comment: yes i'm sure, i understand the confusion there similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it through simple steps; 
verify first with a bit of debug that your code is reaching OnControllerColliderHit, then reaching OpenDoor(hit.gameObject); 
Also confirm that it can play door.transform.parent.animation.Play("doorOpen"); (and make a sound in normal code rather than conditional)

From the code snippet it may be that your "playerDoor" definition is incorrect elsewhere

Comment: i feel like such an idiot it was just as simple as playerDoor was done as playerdoor you gotta kick yourself at moments like this

Comment: oh and thanks i wouldn't have thought if you didn't mention it

Comment: We've all been there; the more you look at code the more you can miss sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Project` then `Book Assets Folder` then `sounds folder` then drag `Door_open` sound to these variables:

`var doorOpenSound : AudioClip;`
   `var doorShutSound : AudioClip;`

Your sound will play.